# Why if I assign an id to my checkbox, it no longer passes the change in value it undergoes to the controller?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have an MVC application,
I am trying to add a new checkbox to a PartialView, initially I did some tests to make sure that this works correctly and passes the values to the controller, and it did.
Then I added a script that blocks some textboxes if the checkbox in question is True, the problem is that they assign the id to the checkbox, the controller no longer receives the value "True" when I check.
I thought it might be the script I wrote that was causing problems, so I mentioned it, but it still doesn't work, as soon as I remove the id from the checkbox it works again.
How can I fix this?

```
 <div class="col-md-4" id="container">
    <label class="lblForm">  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OnBds, "On BdS ", new { id = "BDS" })</label>
    <div class="d-flex">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.OnBds , new { @onChange = "ValueCheck", id = "BDSCh" })
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried to insert a HiddenFor and assign it the value True through a script, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 2):

Is it a single checkbox? and you have attach a fixed ID to the checkbox, doesn't it help and how new IDs are attached to it? It will be helpful if you could share debug image of your page using chrome or firefox developer tools

Comment: Thanks to your answer I analyzed the code from the chrome development tool, the solution was not created by me, I'm doing maintenance so many things are mysterious for me, removing the fixed id that I assigned as in the screen above, I noticed that automatically the checkbox is assigned a dynamic ID, using this everything was solved...
Thanks for the inspiration you gave me!